# Outlook trying to autodiscover server that no longer exists

Tags: exchange, outlook

Autodiscover seems to have a lot of similar issues, but this one case existing solutions don't seem to help...

Has the common "Allow this website to configure  server settings?".  However, the server listed below is a server that was removed years ago.  The alert is popping up suddenly on a computer (which has been in service for over a year now without having popped this before) that wasn't even around when that server was in production...

There are no autodiscover settings in DNS for that old server.  I've verified that they only point to the correct new server.  I've done registry "find" on the incorrect server name and also have come up empty.

This is just he latest occurrence of this, it's not a one-off event.  It's not been one specific user or PC over the years.  Previously I wrote it off as something cached locally as the computers were old enough as they may have been around when the old server was in production.  However, now I have one where that definitely is not the case.

Comment: When you removed the old server did you uninstall Exchange?

Comment: Agree with joeqwerty, this is usually about the legacy Exchange server. Check the Autodiscover SCP and URL, they should be the new server.

Comment: @joeqwerty Unfortunately I do not know exactly how it was done as I did not do the Exchange replacement/upgrade myself.

Comment: @Louisl Autodiscover SCP and URL are indeed pointed appropriately.  That old server is not in there.  Seems like something deeper is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure any public/private DNS record for autodiscover.domainname.com got the same information, the correct IP for your autodiscover to work.

As for me it seem most likely a DNS error.

If the problem occur from the public side, make sure any redirection in any router point to the correct server.

Keep in mind that if Outlook can't resolve **autodiscover.domainname.com** it failback to try with **domainname.com** directly. Such request could easily backfire if you have old server in your DNS's console for your parent domain.

Comment: We're hybrid Exchange with split zone DNS.  Internally autodiscover is all on the new server and the old one doesn't show up forward or reverse.  Externally everything is pointing at Exchange OnLine.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch When it happen, can you do a nslookup from the faulty computer ? to find if the old server get sent to Outlook from the DNS ? as I dont think your server itself is in error especially if the SCP are correctly configured. (As Outlook dont reinvent the wheel there it just ask the DNS, unless a entry is manually done inside the host file in exemple)

Comment: If I do DNS lookup from the offending computer, that domain name does not even resolve and autodiscover points to our new one...

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch To further diagnostic, if you hold CTRL and right click Outlook you could check the network status, and see where it connect too. You can select to test the autodiscover from there to see the status, let me know if you find something suspicious there